# Is there a way to NOT refresh the page in JSF with commandButton?

Tags: java, javascript, html, xhtml

I have a js that changes the style of a link, it works, but when the command button is pressed and the value is changed, the whole page refreshes and the changes from the js dosent save.

Is there a way to either save the changes with js or xhtml, or is there a way to still send the commands but not refresh the whole site.

My code :

```
<div id="nav">
<h:dataTable value="#{moduleBean.getModuleList()}" var="u">
    <h:column>
        <h:link value="Module#{u.moduleID}" outcome="module" onclick="changeClass(this);" styleClass="modulbarInactive" >               
            <f:param name="moduleID" value="#{u.moduleID}" /> 
        </h:link>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: After `changeClass(this);` put `return false;` and it will cancel the event

Comment: Add an `<f:ajax>` element inside (or around) your <h:commandButton>.